# Creation Form Recognizer Missing Fields

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I'm trying to create a Form Recognizer from the link of the approval e-mail I received.
But I'm not able to select the location or the pricing while creating my resource from Azure Portal. 
I am using correct subscription ID which I gave you at registration.

Different browsers (Firefox, Chrome).
Different Azure Storage Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to using a different subscription than the one provided in the access request. If you have several subscriptions please make sure you are logged into the subscription provided in the access request. Using Incognito and logging into Azure with the e-mail associated to the subscription provided in the access request might assist.

Comment: I only have this Azure account, I requested the authorization and receive the access in the same e-mail.

Comment: Please reply back to the welcome e-mail with your subscription ID.